# Dreamfactory: Database connection to Postgres

Tags: postgresql

1. First I set up the dream factory by "Bitnami Installer for Windows". Following to https://github.com/dreamfactorysoftware/dsp-core/wiki/Install-Microsoft-Windows
2. Then I follow this [add-a-rest-api-to-any-sql-db-in-minutes](http://blog.dreamfactory.com/add-a-rest-api-to-any-sql-db-in-minutes) to add Services to my Remote Postgres Database.
3. On the "API Docs" tab, it is success to call the GET /db operation. ( getTables() - List all table names).
4. I got the following error when trying to call GET /db/{table_name} operation ( getRecordsByFilter() - Retrieve one or more records by using a filter).

Please help

```
[app][ERROR    ] CDbCommand::fetchAll() failed: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "field_name"
LINE 1:   SELECT k.column_name field_name
                               ^. The SQL statement executed was:       SELECT k.column_name field_name
            FROM "information_schema"."key_column_usage" k
            LEFT JOIN "information_schema"."table_constraints" c
              ON k.table_name = c.table_name
             AND k.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
           WHERE c.constraint_type ='PRIMARY KEY'
                AND k.table_name = :table
                AND k.table_schema = :schema.
```

Comment: Please provide more context. It is unclear how do you get into such a situation.

Comment: @ihor : The content is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the version of PostgreSQL you are connecting to. It turns out that omission of `as` keyword is supported starting from 8.4.

Here's a quote from [8.4 release notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/release-8-4.html#AEN97290) section *E.23.3.3. Queries*:

> Allow AS to be optional when specifying a SELECT (or RETURNING) column
>   output label (Hiroshi Saito)
>
> This works so long as the column label is not any PostgreSQL keyword;
>   otherwise AS is still needed.

Therefore `SELECT k.column_name field_name` is not valid for 8.3 and below, but `SELECT k.column_name AS field_name` would work.

If PostgreSQL version is the cause of your problem you have several options:

1. update the database to 8.4 and above;
2. patch the Dreamfactory codebase yourself to work around this problem;
3. raise a ticket in Dreamfactory's bug tracker and wait them to fix it for you.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. We are using the PostgreSQL version is 8.3.

Comment: Hi @Ihor, can you give me some information about "patch the Dreamfactory codebase yourself to work around this problem;"

Comment: @Vince, brief exploration has shown that the problem is in Yii framework that is being used by Dreamfactory, not Dreamfactory itself. Unfortunately I couldn't find the exact place to patch.